# Google Leaderboard

Tags: android, leaderboard

I am developing a game with Google Leader board but the links that Google provides of github which is https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples. Can someone explain please?

So as the github explains i need to import BaseGameUtils into my project and replace the MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity to MainActivity extends BaseGameUtils. After changing it implements 2 methodsafterSign and signinFailed, which i dont understand what to do. And after that the app runs and closes automatically.

{05-26 15:06:37.809 13629-13629/com.lisbonlabs.pokoto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.lisbonlabs.pokoto, PID: 13629
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zza.zzu(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zze.zzxH(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)}

Comment: So as the github explains i need to import BaseGameUtils into my project and replace the MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity to MainActivity extends BaseGameUtils. After changing it implements 2 methodsafterSign and signinFailed, which i dont understand what to do. And after that the app runs and closes automatically.

Comment: If you have an app that closes automatically, it's crashing, and you need to show us your logcat

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred.

Comment: at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zza.zzb(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zza.zzu(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zze.zzxH(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a properly formatted logcat

Comment: I am having real trouble. How do i include logcat sir ? By taking an screenshot ?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, copy it as text as you have and paste in an [edit], then use the `{}` button to format it

Comment: Is it like this?

Comment: cricket_007 Is there any chance that i can contact you via email?

Comment: You'd have better luck with opening a github issue. I've never used that library and that logcat is not helpful. You are trying to  "Check the logs for further information"... Lol

Comment: I succesfully introduced the the library but the problem is it doesnt detect the login information even after i have play games app of google. It shows the animation of connecting to app and at the end says login failed on the mobile screen.

Comment: Again, never used it. But you should now edit your question to include all those details and the section of code that you think is the problem

Comment: Sorry forgot to reply after the last comment. Yes, I already went to issue section of the github and starting to post the issue. Thank you for your guidance.